# Synonym request: [normalization] and [database-normalization]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

[normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization) has been around 7 years and has 1713 questions.

[database-normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-normalization) has been around 5 years and has 526 questions.

Both tags relate to the same thing and the tag wikis are almost identical

I believe one should be a synonym for the other (maybe [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization) should be the base tag).

I don't have rep enough in any of the tags to directly suggest a synonym so asking here.

Comment: Voting to close my request as it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database-layouts are not and never were the only thing which can and sometimes should be normalized.

All kinds of data, audio, video, whatever can and are normalized, and until earlier this year [the tag-excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5839254/revisions) for [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization) reflected that.
The tag-wiki started to reject normalizing anything but databases sometime in 2012 https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5839253/revisions.

There are (still) some good non-database normalization questions (left), how should those be retagged then?

[This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=12&tab=relevance&q=%5bnormalization%5d%20-%5b*database*%5d%20-%5b*sql*%5d%20-%5boracle%5d%20-%5bmongodb%5d%20is%3aq) filters most database-normalization-questions out of normalization.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that the tag used to have another use. I guess that invalidates my request. I see that you reverted the excerpt and wiki to the older state so I guess the problem is solved. Good work!