# Quest for [canonical] [normalization]

Tags: discussion, support, tags, synonym-request

A synonym to break, many synonyms to make, all in the name of normalization:

- [denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denormalization) ← [denormalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denormalized)

  Is that really only about databases, or generally denormalizing data and the pitfalls associated with it? ([A query for finding questions supporting the latter interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bdenormalization%5d%20-%5b*sql*%5d%20-%5b*sql*%5d%20-%5b*database*%5d%20-%5bmongodb%5d%20-%5bravendb%5d%20-%5bcassandra%5d%20-%5boracle%5d%20is%3aq))
  Should it be renamed / synonymized [database-denormalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-denormalization), or just tagged that way where appropriate?
- [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalization) ← [canonical-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canonical-form) [canonicalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canonicalization) [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalize) [normalizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normalizing) ([canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canonical), currently improperly synonym of [canonical-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canonical-link))
- I'm not sure the [third-normal-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/third-normal-form) should have its own tag separate from [database-normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-normalization), but won't yet propose any course there.

<sub>Inspired by investigating [Synonym request: [normalization] and [database-normalization]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306385).</sub>

Comment: To add something: [unicode-normalization] is around for a while, do we really need [text-normalization]? Or is it an idea to replace all [unicode-normalization] tags with [text-normalization] and add the [unicode] tag to those questions? Just wondering...

Comment: I agree. I also noticed that some questions are tagged with both tags, which is weird in my opinion.